# 「ボーダー」... What border?

Tags: english-to-japanese, connotation

My gf loves me wearing striped shirts, as I'm not a skinny person (Japanese standard skinny, stateside I'm skin and bone) they naturally make me look fat!

She always says "ボーダーが好き" and I always think "No, I hate the the (Mexican/Canadian/Any border! ...Tijuana is dope though!)

Why ボーダー？ Why not ストライプ or something?

Comment: She said 「ボーダー」, not "border", right?  Those are two different things.  When Japanese-speakers says 「プリン」, they refer to "flan" 99.9% of the time, not "pudding".

Comment: Why can't translations be 1=いち... lol

Comment: @keepkun I don't know vertical striped shirts.

Comment: Another example that makes me wonder more and more why Japanese people love katakanizing everything instead of using more classical Japanese words. How about just  縦線 and 横線.. or why not using the kanji 縞  to make up a word? I actually think 縞々 means just "striped".

Comment: @Tommy Try think what "horizontal stripes" would be in Japanese? よこしま?

Comment: Lol.. Yeah that sounds funny but homophonous words are everywhere in Japanese anyway (if your point was the confusion with 邪ま). Of course my question deep down would be much more general and would require more details and explanations of course. Here I just wanted to throw in there something I got to think about  a lot recently (and I was a bit provocative on purpose :).

Answer (score 14, accepted):

ストライプ vs. ボーダー

=

Vertical Stripes vs. Horizontal Stripes

[image]

Until about two decades ago, both were called 「ストライプ」.  Then, the fashion industry people invented the name 「ボーダー」 to refer to "horizontal stripes" as a buzzword to make it popular and did they ever succeed!

Comment: So vertical "ストライプ"=ストライプ but horizontal "ストライプ"=ボーダー?

Comment: They're both "stripes"! haha

Comment: That's like calling a pink pig a pig and calling a light pink pig something else...

Comment: keepkun, or rather like calling a pink pig a pig, but a hairy pig a boar, which is exactly what people are doing. I think that it's great that languages evolve and incorporate conveniences into them. With this you say "border" instead of the long and tedious "horizontal stripes"

Comment: @Genos Meanwhile in China, [a white horse isn't a horse](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/When_a_white_horse_is_not_a_horse).

Answer (score 0):

[ボーダー](https://ja.wikipedia.org/wiki/%E3%83%9C%E3%83%BC%E3%83%80%E3%83%BC%E6%9F%84) is a strange word used for a *trend* fashion among of jevenile, young and middle age generations.

And I have no idea why this is also a border dress...
[image]